# trouble with CORS on dropwizard and jquery

Tags: jquery, cors, dropwizard

Having trouble getting CORS to work with Dropwizard and jquery.

Set up this on Dropwizard:

```
environment.addFilter(CrossOriginFilter.class, "*")
  .setInitParam("allowedOrigins", "*")
  .setInitParam("allowedHeaders", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Authorization,Access-Control-Request-Method")
  .setInitParam("allowedMethods", "OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,HEAD");
```

and on the client side:

```
$.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                },
                data: {'taduID': taduId }, // get the form data
                crossDomain: true,
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/tadu/getTaduFromId?id' + taduId,
                success: function(response) { // on success..
                    console.log(response);          
                }
            });
            return false;
```

however getting this in chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://0.0.0.0:8080/tadu/getTaduFromId?id94339742-4381-46f2-b004-38a2d73b68bf. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here is request/response

```
Remote Address:0.0.0.0:8080
Request URL:http://0.0.0.0:8080/tadu/getTaduFromId?id94339742-4381-46f2-b004-38a2d73b68bf
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:204 No Content
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, x-csrftoken, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:0.0.0.0:8080
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8000
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8000/m/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
id94339742-4381-46f2-b004-38a2d73b68bf:
Response Headersview source
Allow:OPTIONS,GET,HEAD
Date:Wed, 30 Apr 2014 18:23:24 GMT
```

I'm sure there is a lot wrong here, but where to start? Have a hunch i've set up something wrong in Dropwizard

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web filter to resolve this problem, the Jetty have a Cross Origin Filter you can use this filter.

Comment: I think that's what the environment.addFilter(... is doing, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: which version of dropwizard you use? In version v0.6.2 or lower the jetty cors filter doesn't work, you need create a Web Filter, you can look this link:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

This example uses Spring more filter is equals in Dropwizard.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a response with HTTP status 204 (no content).
Are you sure `/tadu/getTaduFromId?id94339742-4381-46f2-b004-38a2d73b68bf` actually returns any content is not a `void` method?

Other than that, your CORS-filter looks correct, there are ways for you to implement your own filter and registering that depending on what Dropwizard version you are using.